# gradlew: could not determine java version from '15'

Tags: java, minecraft

Вообщем прикол таков: Хочу сделать мод для minacraft версии 1.7.10 параллельно учить java, скачал forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10 src питаюсь запустить установку gradlew setupDecompWorkspace и получаю ошибку `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception *What went wrong: Could not determine java version from '15'`
jdk-15 установленная и в среду PATH добавлена.
содержимое файла gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Wed Jul 02 15:54:47 CDT 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-bin.zip
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: поставьте 14 или 11 JDK, скорее всего gradle ещё не обновился для работы с 15 версией

Comment: @Komdosh Да спасибо это сработало но возникла другая проблема примерно через 2m37s вилезает ошибка вот такая:
>Failed to apply plugin 'forge'.
   >Could not create task ':reobf'.